# Unexpected EOFError raised by pickle.load(). Is the file corrupted or what?

Tags: python, pickle, pypy

I am experiencing an odd problem while loading a particular file with pickle.

I am using PyPy on OSX. The files were originally generated with the same configuration using, obviously, pickle.dump().
The code below iterates over the pickled files and attempt to read them. Most of the files got loaded successfully but some (two found up to now) does not.
Each file is around 64MB and I have plenty of RAM. What can be the cause of the error?

```
poolFiles = get_all_files('../test','.pool')
counter = Counter()
for p in poolFiles:
    print p
    with open(p,'rb') as f:
        bots = pickle.load(f)
        for botID, genome in bots.iteritems():
            counter.update({botID})

../test/best_performers.pool
../test/best_performers_01.pool
../test/best_performers_02.pool
../test/best_performers_03.pool
../test/best_performers_04.pool
../test/best_performers_05.pool
../test/best_performers_06.pool
../test/best_performers_07.pool
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-22bb8d4b58db> in <module>()
      5     print p
      6     with open(p,'rb') as f:
----> 7         bots = pickle.load(f)
      8         for botID, genome in bots.iteritems():
      9             counter.update({botID})

/usr/local/Cellar/pypy/5.3.0/libexec/lib-python/2.7/pickle.pyc in load(file)
   1425 
   1426 def load(file):
-> 1427     return Unpickler(file).load()
   1428 
   1429 def loads(str):

/usr/local/Cellar/pypy/5.3.0/libexec/lib-python/2.7/pickle.pyc in load(self)
    899             while 1:
    900                 key = read(1)
--> 901                 dispatch[key](self)
    902         except _Stop, stopinst:
    903             return stopinst.value

/usr/local/Cellar/pypy/5.3.0/libexec/lib-python/2.7/pickle.pyc in load_eof(self)
    921 
    922     def load_eof(self):
--> 923         raise EOFError
    924     dispatch[''] = load_eof
    925 

EOFError:
```

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without knowing how the files were created (which is likely the source of the problem).

Comment: `with open(filepath,'wb') as f: pickle.dump(pool,f)` of course, and they were all made at the same time, from the same script.

Comment: Then it may be a bug?  We'd welcome instructions about how to reproduce it to https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues?status=new&status=open

Comment: I can't figure it out, I have run everything a second time and not no corrupted files were found, so I cannot reproduce the error.